# Different types of drug patents but which is most related to APIs?

Tags: drugpatent

there are several types of drug patents, such as salt, formulation, composition, combination, dose, isomers, polymorphs, active metabolites/prodrug, method of treatment and second use.

My question is: as a generic pharmaceutical company, we sell our active ingredients to other countries. Which types of drug patents that we should most concern about in order that our API do not infringe others?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only exporting API (active ingredient), then you should check following patents Salts, process of making, isomer, impurities, polymorphs, active metabolites, prodrugs, hydrates, reagents, reaction conditions, catalysts, purification methods, assay techniques.

if its combination of API then you have to cover formulation, composition, combination patents, formulations, excipients, packaging.